# trigger click event function only once, poll, fiddle Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm developing this poll,

**PROBLEM**

I need to set the poll with default values once the page starts (see the code)....there is this inital jumping backwards motion  I dont want to.

I trigger the main click event, but this adds up `1 vote` to each option... http://jsfiddle.net/hhgg6d4z/1/

**EXPECTED**

I dont want the trigger to add up 1 vote to each option...but once the default percentages are set, make posible to continue voting...Its supposed to display to the user the ongoing poll votes....

**SNIPPET**

```js
var entry_1=10; //votes by default
var entry_2=20; //votes by default
var sum = entry_1 + entry_2; 


var PollDefaultSet =0;
 
$(".entry").on("click",function(){ 

/*
if(PollDefaultSet ==0){
entry_1=entry_1; 
entry_2=entry_2;  
sum = entry_1 + entry_2; 
 PollDefaultSet =1;
 
}

if(PollDefaultSet ==1){}
*/


if($(this).hasClass("entry1")){
  entry_1++; sum = (entry_1 + entry_2); 

}if($(this).hasClass("entry2")){ 
 entry_2++;  sum = (entry_1 + entry_2); 
 
}




 var topP= Math.floor((entry_1/sum)*100);
 var mid0P= Math.floor((entry_2/sum)*100);

 
  var totalP = topP + mid0P;
 
 
 var total_op1= totalP -(mid0P);
 var total_op2= totalP -(topP);


 $(".entry1").find("b").text(total_op1+ "%"); 
 $(".entry2").find("b").text(total_op2+ "%"); 


 $(".total_votes span").text(sum);

 $(".entry1 .PollPercentageBG").animate({width: total_op1+"%"});
 $(".entry2 .PollPercentageBG").animate({width: total_op2+"%"});
 


 
}).click();
```

```css
.ShowPollContainer{
 margin:10px auto;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E8ED;
}
.entry{
 margin:8px auto;
 position:relative;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 width:90%;
 qborder:1px solid #F0F0F0;
 overflow:hidden;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.entry .PollPercentageBG{
 display:block;
 height:100%;
 width:0;
 
 
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
 
}
.entry div{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:left;
 qfont-weight:bold;
 padding-left:20px;
 top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
 z-index:9;
 

}
.entry b{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 width:auto;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:10px;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
 z-index:11;
 qbackground:red;
 padding:0 5px;
 text-align:center;
}
.entry .PollBase{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 height:35px;
 width:10px;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 z-index:12;
 qbackground:blue;

}

.entry .PollPercentageBG{
 max-width:80%;
}
.entry1 .PollPercentageBG{
 background:#5CA733; 
}
.entry1 .PollBase{
 background:#5CA733; 
}
.entry2 .PollPercentageBG{
 background:#FFC800;
}
.entry2 .PollBase{
 background:#FFC800;
}

.total_votes{text-align:left;margin:10px auto 20px auto;width:90%;color:#899AA7;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='ShowPollContainer' >


<div class='entry entry1'>
<span class='PollPercentageBG'></span>
<div>First Option </div><b>0%</b><span class='PollBase'></span>
</div>


<div class='entry entry2'>
<span class='PollPercentageBG'></span>
<div>Second Option </div><b>0%</b><span class='PollBase'></span>
</div>
<div class='total_votes'> total votes <span>0</span> · </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use websockets to process votes or something like websockets if you have multiple browsers participating in the poll, so that each vote is propagated to every browser.

For a single browser, you can initialize the values with a refactored function instead of triggering the click method to initialize the fields:

```
var entry_1 = 10;
var entry_2 = 20;
var sum = entry_1 + entry_2;

var displayPercentages = function() {
    sum = (entry_1 + entry_2); 

    var topP = Math.floor((entry_1/sum)*100);
    var mid0P = Math.floor((entry_2/sum)*100);    

    var totalP = topP + mid0P;

    var total_op1= totalP -(mid0P);
    var total_op2= totalP -(topP);

    $(".entry1").find("b").text(total_op1+ "%"); 
    $(".entry2").find("b").text(total_op2+ "%"); 

    $(".total_votes span").text(sum);

    $(".entry1 .PollPercentageBG").animate({width: total_op1+"%"});
    $(".entry2 .PollPercentageBG").animate({width: total_op2+"%"});
}

displayPercentages();

$(".entry").on("click",function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("entry1")) {
        entry_1++;
    } else if($(this).hasClass("entry2")) { 
        entry_2++;
    }

    displayPercentages();
});
```

Comment: single browser by now...but it works...no need to trigger, ok thank you!!